# C# Custom Sort by a enum or list

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting

I need to build a sorter class for a List.

I would like the sort rule or priority to be:

> SFC = 1 SSG = 2 SGT = 3 CPL = 4 SPC = 5 ETC...

So when I sort I will get these in the correct order by rank first then by lastname.

```
List<Person> person = new List<Person>(); 
person.Rank
person.LastName
person.FirstName
```

ETC...

Please lead me to an article or instruction. Thanks

Comment: This is enum `SFC = 1 SSG = 2 SGT = 3 CPL = 4 SPC = 5 ETC...`?

Comment: Not sure if this will make a difference but I am populating the person.Rank from a datasource so it is a String type, should have mentioned this sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public enum Rank
{
    SFC = 1, SSG, SGT
}

public class Person
{
    public Rank Rank { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var persons = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person{ Name = "Aaaa", Rank = Rank.SFC },
        new Person{ Name = "Bbbb", Rank = Rank.SFC },
        new Person{ Name = "Aaaa", Rank = Rank.SSG }
    };

    foreach (var person in persons.OrderBy(p => p.Rank).ThenBy(p => p.Name))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", person.Rank, person.Name);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
SFC Aaaa
SFC Bbbb
SSG Aaaa
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you use LINQ?

```
person.OrderBy(p => p.Rank).ThenBy(p => p.LastName)
```

or using the query syntax with the [orderby](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383982.aspx) clause:

```
from p in person
orderby p.Rank, p.LastName
select p
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var ordered = person.OrderBy(p => p.Rank)
                    .ThenBy(p => p.LastName)
                    .ThenBy(p => p.FirstName);
```

Note that this does NOT modify `person`. It merely produces an iterator that when iterated over yields the results of `person` returned in the specified ordering. If you want to modify the list you'll have to take a slightly different approach (note that it's not enough to say `person = ordered.ToList();` as that actually creates a new instance of `List<Person>`.

Answer (score 0):

using linq

```
var list = from xx in person
order by xx.Rank, xx.LastName
select xx
```

it will sort by rank and last name

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
 var result = from m in person
             orderby m.Rank, m.LastName
             select m;
```

or you can try this....

```
 var result = person.OrderBy(m=> m.Rank) 
                .ThenBy(m => m.LastName) 
                .ThenBy(m => m.FirstName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class Person should inherit from the interface Icomparable. Doing so you'll have to implement the compareto() method. Then you can use the sort method of the List.